# How to find a publisher for a a science fiction novella

Tags: publishing, science-fiction, novella

I've always tried writing novels, and have just recently discovered how much I actually enjoy writing a novella!

I'm getting very close to sending it out to beta readers, and have started looking online for potential publishing companies to whom I can submit. My problem is that most places (i.e. Tor) seem to only accept novellas during limited times.

How can I identify publishers that I might try submitting my SciFi novella to?

Comment: Relevant: [Are novellas marketable?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/20457/26)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What publishers have published the sci-fi novellas you've read? Try them first.

This line of research works whether you're writing short stories (look at the collections where they appear for lists of the journals where the stories have been previously published) or full-on novels (who's the publisher for them?).